# Internal server error - apache 2.4 & mod_perl

Tags: linux, apache, perl, cgi

I keep getting an internal server error when accessing my forum, i recently transfered the files from my windows machine onto linux, which I got from another linux machine. I manually edited all the paths in the source files (There is no configuration file, had to do it manually) and changed the database configuration details to match my db info on this machine, however I've run into another problem;

[image: server error message]

[Here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/products/gossamer-forum/requirements.html) are the requirements for the forum, they've all been met.

Is the problem being caused from skipping the installation of the modules? AFAIK I've copied everything from the previous installation that was all fine and dandy, if so could i just download, install a fresh copy then transfer my previous files?

Answer (score 0):

The GForum directory is not in the search path. To fix this, configure the `@INC` search path, see [the perl faq](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.14.4/pod/perlfaq8.pod#How_do_I_add_a_directory_to_my_include_path_(@INC)_at_runtime?).

Secondly, Apache may not have read permissions for the module directory, parent directories or for the module itself.

Comment: one of the first lines is `use lib '/srv/http/cgi-bin/admin'`, and inside the admin folder is the GForum folder with all the perl modules, so it should be in the path

Comment: If added a note to the answer regarding the file permissions. Can you include a long list of the directory and module file permissions?

Comment: The file permissions should allow the server to read Category.pm. How about the directory where it resides? And its parent directories? ls -ld /srv/http/cgi-bin/admin/GForum

Comment: Also, what is the effective user id of the server? ps -ef | grep httpd

Comment: Also double check your use lib statement because it's not printed as part of your @INC search path of your screenshot. This should be solved first.

Comment: i had the wrong apache configuration on how it handles cgi and perl scripts, it's all fine and dandy now. o7